# Get header from request in service layer of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, header

Is there any way in spring boot to grab header from request in any point of application? 
Some static stuff will be great.

Please, be aware that `@RequestHeader` does not work for me since I need this value on service layer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can inject `HttpServletRequest` object in your service layer like this :

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;

private void method() {
  request.getHeader("headerName");
}
```

but remember, that bean `HttpServletRequest` has HTTP request scope. So, you can't inject that into asynchronous methods etc, because it will `throw Runtime Exception`.

hope it helps.

Answer (score -4):

I was searching the same question before, i found out that you can use header parameters in the RestController methods with @RequestHeader as you said. So why not direct them into your service layer methods:

```
@Autowired
ServiceLayerObj serviceLayerObj;
...
@RequestMapping
public YourReturnObj someRestServiceMethod(
    @RequestBody SomeObj body,
    @RequestHeader(value = "username") String username
){
    return serviceLayerObj.yourServiceLayerMethod(body,username);
}
```